# How to change language of Scientific WorkPlace?

Tags: editors, french

I'm a student in faculty of mathematics and they require us to work with SWP.

My problems are:

- the exported PDFs shows some default words in English and I want the whole document to be in French. I did try "babel" but it gives me some unwanted results! for example instead of "1ere partie" [1st part] I want it to show "chapitre 1" [Chapter 1].
- When I add new clause an auto-increment number shows beside for example, theorem , theorem 1, theorem 2, etc... even if I'm in the same chapter; So I want to get ride of those AI numbers or at least make them restart from 0 each new chapter.

Please! Help me to solve those problems.

Comment: I don't understand: if you write your text in French, the output should really be in French. Do I miss something?

Comment: Do you want Scientific Workplace to have a French interface?

Comment: Based on a (rather brief) look through the official site, it seems that if you want the interface in French, you are probably out of luck. However, if the problem is that e.g. 'Contents' appears in English even though your text is in French, the use of babel is supported. Your document preamble would then contain e.g. \usepackage[french]{babel}. I don't know if there is a menu option to add this for you automatically or if you just edit the preamble yourself. (I've never used SWP.)

Comment: @zakou SWP is a proprietary product. What does their customer service say?

Comment: As @PredragPunosevac says, as SWP is closed-source we are perhaps a little limited. In a LaTeX context we can answer all of this, but how to interface into SWP may be an issue.

Comment: It is impossible to answer that with the given information. According to the comments, this could as well be about customizing the interface of SWP, which would make it somehow off-topic. Since there was never any feedback, i vote to close as unclear.